# Show custom error page in production only in Play

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

We want to override the standard Play error page with our own error page. Unfortunately, overriding `onError` in our `Global` file replaces the error page in all modes, even though we'd like to keep the informative debug error page in development. How can I detect development mode to retain the built-in behavior in that mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play object has helper methods that allow checking a current application mode.

```
import play.api._

object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  override def onError(request: RequestHeader, e: Throwable): Future[SimpleResult] = {
    if (!Play.isDev)
      Future.successful(InternalServerError(views.html.customErrorPage()))
    else
      super.onError(request, e)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (play.api.Play.current.mode == play.api.Mode.Prod)
  ...
```